# Scrapy crawl with proxy

Tags: proxy, scrapy, http-proxy

I wrote a Scrapy middleware to must use proxy on every request via **scrapy.Request(url)**.

My custom middleware:

> class MyCustomProxyMiddleware(object):
>
> ```
> def __init__(self, settings):
>     self.chosen_proxy = settings.get('ROTATOR_PROXY', None)
>
> @classmethod
> def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
>     return cls(crawler.settings)
>
> def process_request(self, request, spider):
>     if self.chosen_proxy is not None:
>         request.meta["proxy"] = self.chosen_proxy
>         log.debug('Using proxy <%s>' % self.chosen_proxy)
> ```

In my settings.py

> ROTATOR_PROXY = 'http://ip:port'  # This is my rotator gateway proxy

My spider:

> ```
> def start_requests(self):
>     urls = []    # thousand URLs 
>     for url in urls:
>         # Don't redirect URL and scrape data
>         if checkers.is_url(url):
>             yield scrapy.Request(url)
> ```

However, I check the stats of rotator proxy gateway, I see that some firstly **scrapy.Request(url)** using the proxy, but many **scrapy.Request(url)** don't use my rotator proxy gateway. I need all requests must use my rotator gateway.

I cannot guess the problems, please let me know my problems and suggest my bug if possible.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Any reason you are not using an existing middleware for this, like https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/scrapy-rotating-proxies ?

Answer (score 0):

There are various methods to use proxy with scrapy crawler. The first method is to use the traditional way by running the command “pip install scrapy-rotating proxies” and follow the official documentation. The second and most used by developers is the integration of APIs that have pre-built functions to handle proxies along with the support of multiple languages (including python) so that these APIs automatically handle proxy rotation and provides full anonymity. Besides this, you can try the following codes to use proxy with scrapy. But before going for the code, note that in the first source code, we are setting up a proxy by a request parameter and in the second source code, custom proxy middleware is created.

> Method 1:

```
def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        return Request(url=url, callback=self.parse,
        headers={"User-Agent": "scrape web"},
        meta={"proxy": "http:/154.112.82.262:8
```

> Method 2:

```
from w3lib.http import basic_auth_header
class CustomProxyMiddleware(object):
def process_request(self, request, spider):
        request.meta[“proxy”] = "http://192.168.1.1:8050"
        request.headers[“Proxy-Authorization”] = 
basic_auth_header(“<proxy_user>”, “<proxy_pass>”)
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'myproject.middlewares.CustomProxyMiddleware': 350,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 400,
}
```

> Note: Setting proxies by passing it as a request parameter and second method is to create a custom proxy middleware.